# It is necessary to pull remote branch when I need to merge it to another branch?

Tags: git, merge

I have my `master` branch locally. I wanted to merge `feature1` branch which exists only on remote. What is the fastest way to merge it to my `master` branch ? When I am on `master` and try `git merge origin/feature1` its returns "Already up to date."

There is any fastest/better way than this?

```
git checkout feature1
git pull
git checkout master
git merge feature1
git branch -d feature1
```

Comment: I haven't check it , but wouldn't a `git fetch` replace your first 3 steps?

Comment: yes, ```git fetch origin feature1:feature1``` replace first 3 steps thanks.

Comment: How about a `git fetch --all` instead ? I hope it could allow you to skip checkouting to  the feature branch, pulling it and "recheckouting" back to master.

Comment: Kamil make this comment as an answer. works like a charm. Thanks and greetings from Poland ;)

Comment: `git pull origin feature1` is as @torek's damn-near-perfect answer says the quickest way to get there, but (also as he says) you should know that's not necessarily the right where to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a beginner (or even somewhat intermediate) in Git, I recommend that you *avoid* `git pull` entirely. ( What `git pull` did to me, as a beginner in Git back in 2008, was mostly confuse me. :-)  It is better now than it was then, but it's still not that good.)

What `git pull` does is:

1. Run `git fetch` (with some options / arguments).
2. If that succeeds, run a second Git command (with some arguments).

You can choose which Git command it will run.  The default is `git merge`, but the other normal and useful second command is `git rebase`.  This—running `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`—is meant to be more convenient than having to run two separate commands.

But: how do you know which second-command you *should* use, if any?  Well, that depends on more than one thing—but one of the things that it depends on is what gets fetched by `git fetch`.  But `git pull` makes you decide *before* you run `git fetch` and therefore see what `git fetch` fetched!  So as conveniences go, `git pull` is kind of flawed.

#### What I recommend

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/feature1
```

In particular, if you want to see what *came in* when you ran `git fetch`, you need to have Git *stop* after running `git fetch`.  You can then run `git log origin/feature1` to look at it.  Then you can run `git merge origin/feature1`, if that's still what you want to do.  Maybe you don't want to do *either* of the two standard second steps, or at least, not yet.  You will have a clear view of the two steps, and the option to look before you leap into the second step.

#### The combined "convenient" `git pull`

You can, if you're sure you're going to use `git merge`, combine the two steps using the convenience mode:

```
git pull origin feature1
```

#### What the steps are, and what they do

Using `git pull` will run these two commands:

1. `git fetch origin feature1`

   This connects your Git to another Git.  The other Git is the one reachable by calling (texting, phoning, Internet-ing in some way) the URL you've stored under the name `origin`.  Git calls this name a *remote*.

   The other Git has some set of branches (branch names, to be more precise).  One of its branches is, presumably, `feature1`.  Your Git asks their Git what commit its name `feature1` identifies.  Your Git checks whether you already have that commit—probably not, based on your question—and if not, asks their Git for that commit, and that commit's parent, and the parent's parent, and so on, until this chain of parent commits leads to a commit that your Git *does* already have.

   Your Git then stores all of these commits in your own repository.  If your Git is not too ancient (is at least 1.8.2), your Git then remembers their Git's `feature1` by updating your *remote-tracking name* `origin/feature1`.  That's their branch name, but it's not *your* branch, so your Git *renames* it to one of these remote-tracking names.

   Your Git also stores the commit hash ID in the special file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This happens even in really ancient Git versions like the one I started with.  This storage is temporary (it's overwritten by the next `git fetch` you run or have run for you), which is why there's the more-permanent, and better, `origin/feature1` to remember the hash ID for you.

   If you run:

   ```
   git fetch origin
   ```

   without the `feature1` restriction, your Git still calls up their Git as before, but this time it retrieves *all* their branches, and updates or creates *all* your remote-tracking names accordingly.  I recommend doing this, even though it may bring over some things you don't need yet, because if those commits exist with names "over there", that way you'll have them with your own remote-tracking names "over here" in your own Git repository, where you can see them.
2. `git merge -m "merge branch 'feature1' of url" hash-ID`

   This step merges the specific commit that their `feature1`—your `origin/feature1`—names.  That's how Git's merge works anyway (by commit hash ID).  It sets the merge message so that it doesn't just have a raw hash ID.

   If you run your own:

   ```
   git merge origin/feature1
   ```

   the default merge message will be `merge branch origin/feature1`, which is really just as useful.  Neither is a great commit message.  A good one might read something like:

   > merge the implementation of feature X
   >
   > New feature X enables blah blah ... a short
   >   description of what it's all about that the
   >   marketing folks will turn into a sales spiel

   but hardly anyone bothers to write good merge messages.

Note that the `git merge` step may have merge conflicts.  Since merging works by commit hashes underneath, it doesn't really matter which way you get the merge started: it will have the same conflicts, which you'll resolve the same way.